# good practises null object return

Tags: c#, object, null, return

I have a question about c# programming language, when a method returns an object, and for example I'm forced to return null, which is not clean code, what is the best practise to handle this? I dont want to return null.

**EDIT**

This was a question because it started as discussion on a software engineering class after reading *Clean Code - Robert C. Martin* 's book and it really came to my mind that trying to avoid this added unnecesary complexity to the design.

Comment: What's wrong with returning `null` when it's the correct answer? How is that not clean code?

Comment: If you have a specific case you can show (with code), this might be a more answerable question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case to signal "failed to create object" C++ class constructs throws exceptions for this purpose.

Some languages / projects prefer to use exceptions more to keep happy-pass happier while others may not.